# How do I insert variable values in to a table record in an oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I insert variable values in to a table record in an oracle procedure?

```
if pCount1=0 then
            insert into opions(qid,otext,oflag)
            (rec.pQid, rec.pOptions, rec.pCorrect);
end if;
```

where `rec.*` are the variables of the procedure

Comment: The way you asked the question is quite confusing to me. AFAIK, `rec` is a _record_. And from the sample code, you are trying to insert a new _row_ to a table, using some fields of that record as values. Or are you looking for something else ?

Comment: you can use RECORD type too, delcare rec as a RECORD type, for more see the doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for one of these statements (which are functionally equivalent)?

```
        insert into opions(qid,otext,oflag)
            values (rec.pQid, rec.pOptions, rec.pCorrect);


        insert into opions(qid,otext,oflag)
            select rec.pQid, rec.pOptions, rec.pCorrect from dual;
```

This assumes that `rec` is defined somewhere else in the stored procedure.  Otherwise, you need to use the second form with `rec` defined in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOME_PROC AS
  nQid        NUMBER;
  strOptions  VARCHAR2(100);
  strCorrect  VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
  nQid := 1;
  strOptions := 1234;
  strCorrect := 'Y';

  INSERT INTO OPIONS(qid, otext, oflag)
    VALUES (nQid, strOptions, strCorrect);
END SOME_PROC;
```

Best of luck.